# Scraping an image from a webpage at defined scale

Tags: web-scraping, printing-web-page, esri-maps

[image: Screenshot of the reference Webpage]

I am on a task to prepare a map/plan view database for a specific region in Ireland.
However I need to use a specific style of map from myplan.ie website at a defined scale (as highlighted in the screenshot on bottom left, 1unit=30m)

I now manually screenshot the image from my screen and scale it manually to load in on google earth to export as a .kml/.kmz.

I have no programming skills to get this task done (to download the image with larger boundaries than my screen but at required scale at 1-30m). Could someone let me know if this is a possible task even through programming/some quick turnarounds on browser devtools (on chrome/firefox/edge)

Appreciate a comprehensive answer to get this job done.
Thanks in advance!

Best regards

I tried inspect/source element sections to check if I could find a static image at this scale but I am unable to find it specifically but the webpage says I do not have permissions to view/download some set parts of the data within the webpage.

Comment: What is the web page?

Comment: https://viewer.myplan.ie/
That's the link to the webpage but I need the screenshot/image within a defined x/y boundary and at a defined scale as mentioned i.e., 1unit=30m

Appreciate your help

Comment: You should add this link to your original post. Question on SO are meant for developers having issue with code. You don't provide any, I think this is off topic and question will be probably closed. You can hire a web scraping specialist to do the task (like me).

Comment: Gilles, Thanks for the response. Sorry if this is off topic but I thought webscraping is relevant here. Anyway would you be able to let me know/connect with me to give me a quote on this ?

Comment: Check https://sputnick.fr/en